# create batch file from batch file (including / )

Tags: batch-file

I know you can create a batch file from a batch file but this code is not working the "/a" does not make it to the new batch file

the code:

```
set/a points=500
@echo set/a points=%points% >>scoreboard.bat
```

---

the result:

```
set points=500
```

Comment: Are you saying that `/a` is missing in the output?? I cannot reproduce that, the output file contains `set/a points=500` + _space_!

Answer (score 1):

That's because variables are being expanded before the `echo` prints anything. To echo some special chars literally, you have to escape them.

Most of those special chars (`<>|&`) are escaped with a caret: `echo ^>`.

The percent sign instead is escaped by another percent sign: `echo %%`.

To write literally `set /a points=%points%`, write:

```
@echo set /a points=%%points%% >>scoreboard.bat
```

Tip: if you want to write several lines, put them in a command block and redirect it once instead of every single line:

```
(
  echo @echo off
  echo REM new bat file
  echo set /a points=%%points%%
) >scoreboard.bat
```

Comment: I think that the OP indicate that in `@echo set/a points=%points% >>scoreboard.bat` line _the "/a" does not make it to the new batch file_ but produce `set points=500` instead...

Comment: @Aacini: if you are right (and yes, reading the question again, that's what it says) I see no way for that to happen - assuming we're talking about `cmd.exe` and it's native `echo` and `set` commands.

Comment: Thank you, this helps a ton =)

Comment: Aacini I'm using this code to basically save user information to a batch file that can later be reopened(attempting to save the variables from a game after the window is closed)

Comment: @Blaine: Independently of the purpose of the code or the form you write it, there is no way that `@echo set/a points=%points% >>scoreboard.bat` command _omits_ just the `/a` part and output `set points=500`, so you are wrong in your conclusion about "this code is not working"...  @ Stephan: I just pointed out that your answer does not address the problem stated by the OP...